# Calculate %-similarities between different columns

Tags: matrix, google-sheets

I'd like to calculate ***the % of similarities of different columns*** in a Google spreadsheet but I do not know how.

In Google Sheets I have two sheets:

**first** there is a table with several (upcoming) political proposals and how some political parties voted for those proposals. Each of the vote values (yes or no) will be added manually.

**second** there is a block matrix, with the % of two political parties which voted for the same proposals. In this sheet I count from the first sheet the similarities of each party compared to the other parties. Or: *how many times out of X voted two parties exactly the same?*

Some examples:

- Party A voted 2 times exactly the same as party B, and vice versa.
  The formula I use to calculate the % in the block matrix is =2/5.
- Party A voted 1 time exactly the same as party C, and vice versa. The formula I use to calculate the % in the block matrix is =1/5
- Party B voted 2 times exactly the same as party C, and vice versa. The formula I use to calculate the % in the block matrix is =2/5
- Et cetera.

*N.B. The '5' in X/5 is the maximum of  five proposals at this time, but in the near future this amount will grow to a larger number*

Sample [Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rVaWN_FEV0qOk9kCp-SON4r-THsHZMqA5JQb9fNcEnM/edit?usp=sharing).

For now, I calculate the % of similarities manually which seems not very efficient to me and even more time consuming when the number of political proposals increases. I think calculating the % of similarities can be done smarter and more-efficient with a formula, so when I have to add some new vote results, the % of similarities automatically in the block matrix will adjust automatically .

How could I achieve this efficiency improvement?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with matrix multiplication.

This is the formula I used:

```
=ArrayFormula(
    (SUMPRODUCT(
        MMULT(
            (IF('Overview of votes by party'!$B$2:$E$2=B$2;'Overview of votes by party'!$B$3:$E$7)="Yes")*1;
            TRANSPOSE(($B$2:$E$2>0)*1)
        )*
        MMULT(
            (IF('Overview of votes by party'!$B$2:$E$2=$A3;'Overview of votes by party'!$B$3:$E$7)="Yes")*1;
            TRANSPOSE(($B$2:$E$2>0)*1))
    )+
    SUMPRODUCT(
        MMULT(
            (IF('Overview of votes by party'!$B$2:$E$2=B$2;'Overview of votes by party'!$B$3:$E$7)="No")*1;
            TRANSPOSE(($B$2:$E$2>0)*1)
        )*
        MMULT(
            (IF('Overview of votes by party'!$B$2:$E$2=$A3;'Overview of votes by party'!$B$3:$E$7)="No")*1;
            TRANSPOSE(($B$2:$E$2>0)*1)))
    )/
    (
        COUNTIF('Overview of votes by party'!B:B;"Yes")+
        COUNTIF('Overview of votes by party'!B:B;"No")
    )
)
```

Basically the process is:

1. Take the matrix of the two comparing parties values.  i.e.:

   ```
   IF('Overview of votes by party'!$B$2:$E$2=B$2;'Overview of votes by party'!$B$3:$E$7)="Yes")*1
   ```

   and

   ```
   IF('Overview of votes by party'!$B$2:$E$2=$A3;'Overview of votes by party'!$B$3:$E$7)="Yes")*1
   ```
2. Sum of each row in both matrices, creating two new matrices
   (each with dimensions of 1 x #Proposals).  This is done by multiplying each matrix by a single column matrix consisting of all 1's with the same amount of rows as #proposals. i.e.:

   ```
   MMULT(
           (IF(..PartyA..)*1;
           TRANSPOSE(($B$2:$E$2>0)*1)
       )
   ```

   and

   ```
   MMULT(
           (IF(..PartyB..)*1;
           TRANSPOSE(($B$2:$E$2>0)*1)
       )
   ```
3. Multiplying the two matrices from step 2 creating the final matrix
4. Taking the Sum of the matrix created from step 3 using `SUMPRODUCT`
5. Complete 1-4 for "No" and "Yes", add the two sum's together
6. Divide the sum from step 5 by the total number of proposals:

   ```
   (
       COUNTIF('Overview of votes by party'!B:B;"Yes")+
       COUNTIF('Overview of votes by party'!B:B;"No")
   )
   ```

You can see this live [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzDvqv2mZiEELXoVtt4Fb6LAyt7sx3f2LST6h3kYXDo/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Wow, Thank you Chancea! 

Let me check and test your (and Chris Hick's) fantastic codes/formulas for a while.

Thank you so much for your quick and kind solution!

Answer (score -1):

I made a copy of your example sheet that produces the same output.

https://goo.gl/vTpNpa

The formula is in cell B3 of the 'Matrix of similarity' sheet.

Comment: Wow, Thank you Chris! 

Let me check and test your (and Chancea's) fantastic codes/formulas for a while.

Thank you so much for your quick and kind solution!